# Twig render a textarea

Tags: textarea, twig

I just want to render a simple text area I receive from an Entity

```
<h1>Consejo para el hijo {{ hijo.nombre }}</h1>
```

`{{com.recom}}`

It returns me this error message

> Key "recom" for array with keys "0" does not exist in PreditBundle:Consejo:verconsejo.html.twig at line 3

It really makes no sense since in other twigs I've could write stuff like that.

I also add my controller action

```
public function  verconsejoAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $consejo = $em->getRepository('PreditBundle:Consejo')->findByHijo($id);
    $hijo    = $em->getRepository('PreditBundle:Hijo')->find($id);
    return $this-> render('PreditBundle:Consejo:verconsejo.html.twig', array('con'=>$consejo , 'hijo'=>$hijo));

}
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end was more simple than that, for me it worked using

```
$consejo = $em->getRepository('PreditBundle:Consejo')->findOneByHijo($id);
```

and then getting recomendation directly

```
$con     = $consejo->getRecomendacion();
```

so for me it worked using `findOneByHijo();`

Answer (score 0):

Your render method delivers a "con" variable, and you try to access a "com" variable. Also it might be better to use the getters if possible. So try:

```
{{con.getRecom}} or {{con.recom}}
```

Comment: Same error, even using {{con.getRecom}} or {{con.recom}} the field recom is written like that in the DB. Honestly I dont really understand the error message

Comment: Can you check with \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($consejo); ?

Answer (score 0):

By using this statement:

```
$consejo = $em->getRepository('PreditBundle:Consejo')->findByHijo($id);
```

you get an array of items of class Consejo.
So in twig template you get an array. You can get the right value by use:

```
{{con[0].getRecom}}
```

or for example:

```
{% for conObj in con %}
    {{conOjb.getRecom}}
{% endfor %}
```